# PHP shows blank page

Tags: php

Please help any one I am new to php. and Learning php I want to create a project for my organisation. I have install wordpress. Now I want to create a webpage from Mysql database to show date in a table format Here is my code. where is wrong I can't find? It shows a blank page. this is for test purpouse

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Tables from MySQL Database</title>

<style type="text/css">
table.db-table          { border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
table.db-table th       { background:#eee; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
table.db-table td       { padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
/* connect to the db */
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db('test',$connection);

if (!@mysql_select_db('test',$connection)) {
exit('<p>Unable to locate the test ' . 
'database at this time.</p>');
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Annual_Sales, Name,address,phone FROM exampleco");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>   
<tr>
    <td><?=$row['Annual_Sales']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$row['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$row['phone']; ?></td>
</tr>  
<?php
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your server's error logs and get rid of the `@` in `@mysql_select_db` (it suppresses the error).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your root password. You may want to change your mysql root account password **RIGHT NOW**... and then stop using the root account for internet-facing operations.

Comment: What do you mean with a `blank page`, what does the source code look like? Perhaps it's just short tags that is disabled.

Comment: @MarcB most likely its root password of local mysql. have fun hacking it :D

Comment: white page of death= error reporting or display is off

Comment: Developing with error suppression on and possible without error reporting on made me close vote this question

Comment: There is a white page with no error message

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the @ sign ahead of one of your function calls. That will silence any errors thrown by that function.

Read more on that here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Try removing the `@` in front of `@mysql_select_db('test',$connection)` and see if you get anything out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this... It removes the error suppression on the mysql_select_db() functions, and forcefully displays errors in your web browser.

### First Revision

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Report on all errors
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); // Display those errors through the web page.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Tables from MySQL Database</title>

<style type="text/css">
table.db-table          { border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
table.db-table th       { background:#eee; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
table.db-table td       { padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
/* connect to the db */
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db('test',$connection);

if (!mysql_select_db('test',$connection)) {
exit('<p>Unable to locate the test ' . 
'database at this time.</p>');
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Annual_Sales, Name,address,phone FROM exampleco");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>   
<tr>
    <td><?=$row['Annual_Sales']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$row['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?=$row['phone']; ?></td>
</tr>  
<?php
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever you're programming in PHP and that code is not yet ready for production, I *highly* encourage you to make sure errors are being displayed. PHP errors are usually pretty useful and can help the development process along greatly!

### Revision 2

Includes more printing to help track down the problem.

```
<?php
print 'Started.<br />';

error_reporting(E_ALL); // Report on all errors
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); // Display those errors through the web page.

print 'Errors Now Showing. To test, the following line should display an error:<br />';
print $a_var_which_doesnt_exist;
print '<br />';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Tables from MySQL Database</title>

<style type="text/css">
table.db-table          { border-right:1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
table.db-table th       { background:#eee; padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
table.db-table td       { padding:5px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php
/* connect to the db */
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');

if(!$connection) { // Ensure connection successful.
    die('<p>Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
}

$db_sel = mysql_select_db('test', $connection);

if($db_sel) { // Ensure we're able to select database.
    die('<p>Could not select DB: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
}

$result = mysql_query('SELECT Annual_Sales, Name,address,phone FROM exampleco') or die('<p>Error with the query: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');

if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    ?>   
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['Annual_Sales']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['address']; ?></td>
        <td><?=$row['phone']; ?></td>
    </tr>  
    <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <tr><td colspan="4">NO ROWS RETURNED BY QUERY</td></tr>
    <?php
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php print 'Finished.<br />';
```

Comment: I have tried this but no result

Comment: what version of PHP are you running? older versions had some issues where segmentation faults would prevent anything from ever being displayed.

Comment: from the styling you're using, if the database doesn't return any rows you would receive a blank page. try my second example, in which i do a bit more printing to better narrow down the problem.

Comment: I have tried your second revision it says "Could not select DB:" with no error message